TCL read character from process output
I would like to read all the characters from a process output that doesnt output new line.
set process  [open "|program_flash" r ]
while {[gets $process line] >= 0} { puts $line}

Now the problem is like I said when lines with \n are print I get the lines, but in my case it prints something like this.
Part    Start Sector    Num Sectors UUID        Type
  1 63          4208967     00000000-01 0c
Z> 0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...fatwrite ssd 0:1 00000000 ssc.BIN

I would like to print all the percentage values that are later used in another script.
The above line is only printed once it prints till the end.
Much appreciated

Use read with a character count instead of gets

I've tried several times but can't understand exactly what you're asking.   Can you be more specific and add more context?

What I would like to perform is to read characters from the channel output and not lines. Because my channel output outputs in 10% 20% etc and only when it reaches the end it generates a new line or carriage return .

By the way, how is the questions unclear ? I need to read charachters from the process output and not wait for new line or carriage return .

IF I use
set c [read $process 1]  puts "$c"
Its prints everything I need just a single character per line . Is there away to print
like :
puts -nonewline "$c" 
and not wait for carriage return

@dookei I understand better now that you said "not wait for new line".    I didn't realize that you wanted to print characters immediately because the new line was not yet printed.    Also, you used the word "once" to mean "when an event happens", but I think I read it as "occurring only one time"

So the solutions is simple:
while {1} {
    set c [read $process 1]
    puts -nonewline "$c"
    flush stdout
    if {[eof $process]} {
            break
    }
}

Like this is going to print all characters(even when there is no CR/new line) until eof

As long as the process actually writes the data to the pipe, this will work. gets is for reading whole lines.
